# How to reference methods in a class from another class (more details)

Tags: java, class, oop

Class A instantiates Class B inside it.  Class B is unrelated, not a child.  How can class B reference methods inside Class A?

Ex:

```
Class A
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        B newClass = new B();
        // Call method from within B works no problem
        newClass.testMethod();
    }

    public void someImportantMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

However within Class B, how can I call methods from within Class A since I dont have a reference to it?  I figure I could create another object for Class A if i just needed to call methods, but I need to access the **same instance** of Class A that originally instantiated Class B.

Comment: Pass a reference to `this` object to the `B` instance.

Comment: There is no instance of A in your code (`main` is a static method). So when you chose the solution among the ones proposed here under you determine how A instance will be passed to B.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis There is no this there, main is static, so no instance of A exists

Answer (score 2):

```
newClass.testMethod(this);
```

(In this case you cannot use this, because the main() method is static, but you get the point)

and in class B:

```
public Stuff testMethod(A a) {
  a.someImportantMethod();
}
```

Ideally you would reference the A parameter as an interface to reduce the coupling between these two classes, though.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the instance of class A to the method on class B:

```
Class A
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        B newClass = new B();
        newClass.testMethod(new A());
    }

    public void someImportantMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Because it's in a static main method

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

```
Class A
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        B newClass = new B();
        // Call method from within B works no problem
        newClass.testMethod();
    }

    public static void someImportantMethod() //static method, accesible for any instance
    {
    }
}
```

with

```
class B {
    public B() { A.someImportantMethod();}
    ....
}
```

or

```
Class A
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        A obj= new A()
        B newClass = new B(obj);
        // Call method from within B works no problem
        newClass.testMethod();
    }

    public void someImportantMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

with

```
class B {
    private A attr;
    public B(a obj) { a.someImportantMethod();}
    ....
}
```